# How do I import a text file as an array of characters

Tags: python, file-io, text-files

I have a text file that consists of some text.

I want to import this into an array consisting of characters, 
Ex: a file containing "Hello" would become

`['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

I tried using loadtxt (which I usually use for reading data from files) but I think it can only handle actual data (with numbers and stuff). How do I do it?

Comment: YOu already can access "Hello" as a list. Example `for x in "Hello": print x`

Comment: Well, you can make a list of chars - with python lists, or python arrays, or numpy arrays, or byte arrays, what are you really trying to do though?

Comment: @JonClements I'm trying to import a text file consisting of text (eg Lorem Ipsum or something) into an array where each array element is a character from the file (so [0] = L, [1] = o, etc)

Comment: @user2229219 yes - I meant for what purposes - what do you intend to do with it - do you need to be able to mutate it - perform calculators of some sort on it? etc...

Answer (score 3):

This is the usual way to read an entire file:

```
with open("file") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

You can then call `list(content)` to get a list from the string.

Comment: nota : string being both iterable and slicable, there is seldom any reason to make a list out of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load strings using `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
text = np.loadtxt(filepath, dtype = np.str)
```

As others are mentioning, there are other ways of doing this. Furthermore, you can access the individual characters of a string in much the same way as a list.

Comment: That loads it as an array of strings, where each word is one string. It won't let me just put delimiter='', and delimiter=None defaults to whitespace. Any idea on what to use?

Comment: I assume you mean you want a delimiter that splits each individual character? There isn't one. Each string is represented as a character array, so you can easily do `text[0][0][0]` to get the 0th character of the 0th word on the 0th line. Alternatively, if you really want arrays of single characters, then you'll want to use [minty's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19909871/13604), and for each call to `f.read()`, loop through the contents of the string manually to extract each character.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just loop through the file using list comprehension:

```
[i for i in file.read()]
```

Or just convert the string to list:

```
char_list = list(file.read())
```

Keep in mind that this will include special characters, such as tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If NigntCell.txt is your data file and you want to get that text file into a list like as you asked then you could simply use list(content) as rninty suggested. Otherwise if you want to remove the white space from the file then you can use the below code:

> file = open('NigntCell.txt', 'r')
>
> char_list = list(file.read())
>
> space = 0
>
> char_list_len = len(char_list)
>
> for i in range(char_list_len):
>
> ```
>     if char_list[i] == ' ':
>         space +=1 
>     #for other than space add your respective 'counter' code here
> ```
>
> for i in range(space):
>
> ```
>     char_list.remove(' ')
> ```

You can remove other unnecessary characters like '\n' and so, similar to white space above.